# No response from target (vpnc)

Tags: vpn, ipsec, cisco

I'm setting up a new VPN, provided by my university, using `vpnc`. I enter all the details exactly as they tell me, including gateway domain, ID, secret group password, plus my Xauth details. Then run as `sudo vpnc-connect FILE`. I get

```
vpnc: no response from target
```

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457228/ubuntu-10-vpnc-no-response-from-target) and [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=139167) post suggest a firewall problem. However, I have another VPN to which I can connect without problems through `vpnc`. Is it perhaps a problem in the other side of the call?

Comment: @jsotola  why? don't get it.

Comment: @jsotola you literally rephrased the answer, still without providing a reason.